# Ubuntu 21.04. How to get round app icon to appear at center bottom of the app preview?

Tags: gnome

When I was using Fedora 34 a big app icon showed on the center bottom of each app preview. How to do the same in Ubuntu 21.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, Gnome Shell extensions come to the rescue. The  [WindowOverlay Icons by sustmi](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/302/windowoverlay-icons/) adds such icons to the center of the Windows.

In Gnome 40, icons are added by default, at the bottom center of the preview window.